# How do I fix line break in AssemblyInfo.cs when I create project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, every time I create a new project, I have to fix AssemblyInfo.cs because it generates these two lines:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("
        ")]
```

and

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 
         2016")]
```

It did not always do this.  I'm guessing there is a setting somewhere or a template I can fix.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at the project templates on my machine which are located at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates

The `AssemblyCompany` and `AssemblyCopyright` lines show

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("$registeredorganization$")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © $registeredorganization$ $year$")]
```

I suspect that you somehow have a newline character in your `registeredorganization`.

Have a look at this superuser.com question for details of where to find/change it [How can I change the “licensed to” in visual studio?](https://superuser.com/questions/498295/how-can-i-change-the-licensed-to-in-visual-studio). Also note the comment under that question as it may be reading from the Windows registered organization.

You might also want to have a look at the project templates on your machine (see quoted location above), though it seems less likely that the default template has been changed.